# Mini toolbar on text input focus

Tags: css, textinput

I would like to position a mini toolbar on top of a text input on focus (mockup picture below).
[minitoolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujdY5.png)
Please help me with the css of a span or div to place itself right on top the full length of a text input field.

[minitoolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujdY5.png)

Comment: Can you show us please what you have done so far ?

Comment: <div style="margin:0px;">
 <div style="background-color:#039; font-size:14px; padding:2px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; display:block; color:white; text-align:center;">&Pi;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&radic;</div>
 <input type="text" style="width:240px" />
</div>

Problem is that the "toolbar" fills out full width of the screen instead of full width of the text input.

Preferably I would also like to avoid an outer div (and only have one div and one text input), but that is maybe not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieved by including your input and text in a wrapper, making the text position absolute and aligning it to the width of your input.Then just display text on input focus. Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/q3g4db8u/

```
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <span>This is my tooltip</span>
  </div>
</form>

.field {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  display: none;
}

input:focus ~ span {
  display: block;
}
```